# Ruby string slice function

Tags: ruby

```
a = "hello there"
a[/(?<vowel>[aeiou])(?<non_vowel>[^aeiou])/, "non_vowel"] #=> "l"
```

Can anyone explain why `"l"` is returned and not `"h"`?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take your time and [edit] the question to make it readable. Select the code and use the `code` button (`{}`) in the toolbar of the editor to format it nicely.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the first set of brackets in your regex is saying "I'm a vowel", then the second is saying "I'm not a vowel". It doesn't seem to do anything until it's seen a vowel.

Comment: Your code is not valid syntax. I don't know how to reproduce your problem for sure, since the code you provided is clearly not what you're running. Can you please update the question correctly?

Comment: @TomLord the code is valid. Because it was not formatted as code, the `<vowel>` and `<non_vowel>` pieces were interpreted as HTML tags and not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression, piece by piece:

```
/                   # regex delimiter; part of the syntax, not of the regex
  (?<vowel>         # start of a capturing group named "vowel"
  [aeiou]           # matches one char from the class ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o' or 'u')
  )                 # end of the capturing group
  (?<non_vowel>     # start of another capturing group (named "non_vowel")
  [^aeiou]          # matches one character that is not in the class (a consonant)
  )                 # end of the capturing group
/                   # regex delimiter
```

It matches the first vowel that is followed by a non-vowel (a consonant). When the regex matches, the capturing groups capture the matching pieces.

For the string `"hello there"` it matches `el`. The `vowel` capturing group contains `e`, the `non_vowel` group contains `l`.

All of the above are general `regex` information; they are not specific to Ruby, they work the same in other languages.

The code you posted is given as example of the [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method; the documentation explains that the second argument of `str[regex, capture]` is the name of the capturing group to use as the value of the expression when `str` matches `regex`.